# random paste a cell in a column range based on cell value vba excel

Tags: excel, vba

[image]I have names: (A, B, C, and D) and assignments (green, blue, white, yellow ,orange, violet, pink).

What i would like to do is assign the number of assignments for each person and randomly assign the assignments of that person based on the count of assignments i would like them to have. Thanks for any help.

Here is the code of what i tried so far which is based on kutools

```
    Sub CopyData3()
'Update 20140724
Dim Rng As Range
Dim InputRng As Range, OutRng As Range
xTitleId = "Assign"
Set InputRng = Application.Selection
Set InputRng = Application.InputBox("Range :", xTitleId, InputRng.Address, Type:=8)
Set OutRng = Application.InputBox("Out put to (single cell):", xTitleId, Type:=8)
Set OutRng = OutRng.Range("A1")
For Each Rng In InputRng.Rows
    xValue = Rng.Range("A1").Value
    xNum = Rng.Range("B1").Value
    OutRng.Resize(xNum, 1).Value = xValue
    Set OutRng = OutRng.Offset(xNum, 0)
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: What have you tried to do so far? SO is happy to help, but it's not here to write the code for you. Update your question with your attempts

Comment: Hi i'll update my question based on what ive ytried